# Give PHP function class object

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to call a function and supply it with a class? Something like:

```
function foo(class $class) {
  // do something with the class
  echo $class->id;
}

// calling the function
foo(class Bar {
  // supplying the class
  public $id, $username, $password, $time, $ip;
});
```

Comment: No, you can't supply a class definition. You can supply an instantiated object of that class.

Comment: @JonStirling Yeah I knew about the instance of a class, but thanks for confirming :-)

Comment: @Jek your example makes no sense, compared to your question. It looks like you really want the instance of a class. (You do echo $class->id, that would **NOT** be possible on a class definition because theres no instance?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a little confusing but I think you are looking for an [anonymous class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php):

```
function foo($class) {
    echo $class->id;
}

foo(new class {
    public $id;
});
```

Note that anonymous classes are available only for PHP 7+